# C# Initializing a const variable in a method

Tags: c#, methods, constants

If a method in a class has a `const` variable such as:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
   const int myVariable = 5;

   // blah
}
```

will `myVariable` be initialized only once (when the method is called for the first time I believe) or everytime the method is called ?

Comment: Debug it and see for yourself. It is only set on the first call when the line is executed, and no more. I believe that the debugger will actually show how the line is being skipped on the second call (maybe even on the first call?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Neither. Never. Constant are used primarily *at compile time*. It isn't a variable nor a field. The literal value 5 will be used by any code that uses the constant ("ldc.i4.5") - but the constant itself isn't needed for that at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Never. What will happen is that the compiler will burn in that variable into the method: as if it never existed, and just put the value where you put the const's name.

e.g.

```
public double MyMethod()
{
    const int anInt = 45;
    return anInt * (1/2.0) + anInt;
}
```

will get compiled to:

```
public double MyMethod()
{
    return 45 * (1/2.0) + 45; 
    //actually that would also be calculated at compile time,
    //but that's another implementation detail.
}
```